# How to redirect to next page by passing Id and show details in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a json response like this.

```
{
  "response": {
    "data": {
      "students": [{
        "studentsNumber": "123",
        "studentsName": "ABC"

      }, {
        "studentsNumber": "345",
        "studentsName": "CDS"

      }]
    }
  }
}
```

I am doing a request to get the response data. I have a html where i am displaying list with the response data.
My requirment is on click of each list item it should redirect to next html page.For that in the routerLink i am passing studentsNumber like this
students.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let student of studentsData" routerLink="/studentdetails/:{{student.studentsNumber}}" routerLinkActive="active">
      <div>{{student.studentsNumber}}</div>
      <div>{{student.studentsName}}</div>
</div>
```

And in the studentdetails.component.ts

```
constructor(route:ActivatedRoute) {
      this.stuID = route.snapshot.params['studentsNumber'];
  }

   ngOnInit(){
        this.studentdetailsData = this.studentdetailsService.loadStudentsDetails(this.stuID);
        }
```

And in studentdetails.service.ts

```
 loadStudentsDetails(studentNumber:number){
         this.studentDetailsData= this.studentsData.filter(ob => ob.id===Number);
       return this.studentDetailsData;
   }
```

In **loadStudentsDetails** how can I get details of the perticular student by using the **studentsNumber**.
I am trying like this but In the next screen i am getting all the studentdetails not one perticular student details
   Can anyone please help me how to do this.

Comment: Well, by sending an HTTP request to your API that will take the ID in the URL and return the student as JSON.

Comment: In this response only i have all the details data.On click of one list i have to display all the details data in the next page.I canot do one more api call in next screen.@JBNizet

Comment: *I canot do one more api call in next screen*: why couldn't you?

Comment: Because In this response only all datas are coming from backend

Comment: That's why I suggest to make **another** request, to **another** URL: the URL allowing to get the details of one student, identified by its ID, and responding with a different response, containing only that student's information. Just like when you go to `https://stackoverflow.com/users/4675072/ananya` you get the information about one stackoverflow user (you).

Comment: Okay I will try in that way.For now i have edited my questions.Can you please check once the  loadStudentsDetails() method

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#link-parameters-array

Answer (score 0):

You've done a few things wrong, firstly inside your HTML where you're looping, you need to define the `routerLink` as follows:

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let student of studentsData" routerLink="['/studentdetails/', student.studentsNumber]" routerLinkActive="active">
      <div>{{student.studentsNumber}}</div>
      <div>{{student.studentsName}}</div>
</div>
```

Inside the studentdetails component, you need to get the number through the `ActivatedRoute` module, wait for the subscribe action and then only call the get details, please see below:

studentdetails.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params
        .subscribe((params: any) => {
            this.stuID = params['id'] //not sure what your id is called here, it's defined in your route
            this.studentdetailsData = this.studentdetailsService.loadStudentsDetails(this.stuID);
        });
}
```

Your service, you need to select the first item by adding `[0]`, it should look as follows:

```
loadStudentsDetails(studentNumber:number){
    return this.studentsData.filter(ob => ob.id === Number)[0];
}
```

Comment: This is not working ,I am getting error like this.
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:@Wesley Coetzee

Comment: Can you add your routing module so I can see how your routes are set up?

Comment: I am getting studentNumber inside loadStudentsDetails() method.Only thing is I am not able to fetch data based on studentNumber.
 this.studentDetailsData= this.studentsData.filter(ob => ob.id===Number);

Comment: Please add your routing module as well, as you are getting an error saying the routes do not match

Comment: const routes: Routes = [
 
 { path: 'studentdetails/:id',     component: studentdetailsComponent },
 
];
This is my routing module@ Wesley Coetzee

Comment: I tried like this.
loadStudentsDetails(studentNumber:number){
    return this.studentsData.filter(ob => ob.id === Number)[0];
}
But no luck :( @Wesley Coetzee

Comment: I tried like this.
loadStudentsDetails(studentNumber:number){
    return this.studentsData.filter(ob => ob.id === Number)[0];
}
But no luck :( @Wesley Coetzee

Comment: does `this.studentsData` look like the json model, `data`, at the top of your question?

Comment: this.studentsData in console it looks like this.
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]  @Wesley Coetzee

Comment: well that's probably why... how are you fetching that data?

Comment: To fetch data from api where the same above response is there.I am doing like this.
.toPromise()
            .then(res => {
                this.data = res.json().response.data.students;
             
                return this.data;
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);

Comment: Can you tell me anything I am doing wrong.@Wesley Coetzee

Comment: Why not use `Observables` instead? It's hard to determine what's wrong from the information you're giving me.

Comment: @ananya, your`studentsNumber` is a string inside the data object, but you're passing through a number to the service, that's probably why it's not finding any result.