# Navigate to another page with routerlink and get details based on parameter in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a list of items in one page.On click of each list item it should move to next screen and it should show details of that perticular item.
In .html page i am doing router link like this

```
<div *ngFor="let data of productdata" [routerLink]="['/productdetails', data.id]">
....
</div>
```

In productdetails.component.ts file i am getting like this.

```
    ngOnInit(){
private details: any;
 this.details = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number

    });
    }
```

Here i am **getting only ID**.but i **want to get all the details of that ID** also.
Both product and productdetails are using same json data.
This is my json data.

```
{
    "response": {
    "data": {
            "products": [
                {
                    "productNumber": "123",
                    "productName": "ABC"
          },
                 {
                    "productNumber": "345",
                    "productName": "CDS"

                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

In productdetails.service.ts file

```
 loadProductsDetails(productNumber:number){
      this.productsData = this.productService.loadProducts();
      this.productdetailsdata = this.productsData.find(ob => ob.id===productNumber);
      return productdetailsdata;
   }
```

But i am not getting any data in this.

```
this.productdetailsdata = this.productsData.find(ob => ob.id===productNumber);
```

How to acheive this.Can anyone please help me?

Comment: call service to retrieve data related to that ID?

Comment: How to retrieve data related to that ID in Angular2.I am very new to Angular2. @mxr7350

Comment: show your service which return data for list

Comment: I have edited the question  @porgo

Comment: where is ID in your json objects? what id you get in productdetails.component.ts?

Comment: Sorry thats just a small mistake.
it should be like this
this.productdetailsdata = this.productsData.find(ob => ob.id===productNumber);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to next page by passing Id and show details in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46048438/how-to-redirect-to-next-page-by-passing-id-and-show-details-in-angular2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd make a service to share data between components :

**First component HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let data of productdata" (click)="redirectTo('productdetails', data)">...</div>
```

**First component TS**

```
redirectTo(route: string, data: any): void {
    this.mySharedService.data = data;
    this.router.navigateByUrl(`/${route}`);
}
```

**Second component TS**

```
mySharedData: any;
constructor(private mySharedService: MySharedService) {

}

ngOnInit() {
    this.mySharedData = this.mySharedService.data;
}
```

Comment: I tried like this.But the thing is if i am writing this line
 this.router.navigateByUrl(`/${route}`); ,then data is not going to next screen.And if i am not doing data then i can see the data in console but its not redirect to next screen, @trichetriche

Comment: As you can see in my answer, your data is in the service. You don't rely on your router to handle it.

This is usually the way to handle complex data in your application.

Comment: Its working for me.I created a service which i am sharing among both component.Thank you @trichetriche. You solved my problem. :) :)